# How to export a class as readonly but enable internal modifying?

Tags: typescript

Since my class has async init process. I have to define a property readonly public but modify it internally like

```
declare function asyncAppMap(target: string): Promise<Window>

class FrameInternal {
  public readonly content: Window | null = null
  constructor(target: string) {
    asyncAppMap(target).then(app => {
      // Not possible currently.
      // this.content = app
    })
  }
}
```

I am looking for some reusable utility like:

```
class FrameInternal{}
// Then all members of Frame becomes readonly
export const Frame: ReadonlyClass<FrameInternal> = FrameInternal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your specific needs, you could use something like this:

```
type ReadonlyClass<T extends new (...args: any) => any> =
    T extends new (...args: infer A) => infer R ?
    new (...args: A) => { readonly [K in keyof R]: R[K] } : never;
```

The type `ReadonlyClass` converts a constructor type to a new constructor type that produces the same instance type with all its properties marked as `readonly`.

When you export a class constructor you probably also want to export a type with the same name, corresponding to the instance type.  This happens automatically when you use the `class Foo {}` notation (`Foo` is introduced as both the name of the class constructor value, and as the name of the class instance type):

```
export const Frame: ReadonlyClass<typeof FrameInternal> = FrameInternal;
export type Frame = InstanceType<typeof Frame>;
```

Which, when you inspect it, looks like this:

```
/*
const Frame: new (target: string) => {
    readonly content: Window | null;
}
type Frame = {
    readonly content: Window | null;
}
*/
```

That should work at least in the example case you showed above:

```
const f = new Frame("z");
f.content = null; // error, can't assign to read only

function acceptFrame(f: Frame) {
    f.content = null; // error here too    
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXygGcBPdAQQAcKBZKCgCg1gHMQMAueQjGLVZgJScACjBwBbLIRAAeAOp9gOAO4A+AFDrIRQvABiMKOJABJVBhAxUUCPADe6+E-gVkAIwhYw8MHgvnOBVQlZXgAH3hUZAhbAF5I6IhHZ19UbhhkTBwYRhY2TnS+QXtk52ciUjBKGjpcmFYMAQA6DAALEFR6Ogp4WNUSssHnNqkm1P8MXoIqUsGAXwFZufh1Oc0MYgoEACUQKCVUCGIAYWhCQhkAFXgQAA9-YF1UEFD6JveWQk4oVGIBXv6P2I-Vis2udweTxe8DeH3qX3gfEQlngZH+fURqGRMHg23gAH5Zs9Xu8mp9OGiAfZ4HB9ngjvAANoAaUx8AA1iBiDhELiALqcbYsvnwZacZ4AN0sAG5NHcKNlJqluPpDMZBXsDkdTjoZBstjzVUZTOZLNYICCjcYzBYrDZZfLFfB9QgDMapmZuD8wCBLptZC7DW7jKpZeoAPQAKi0eBVwZA4uhdQaBR4RXR-QcZVpWuIPj8HQ48CCIXCCRisrWLqtCHiWecOfpefGhcCihUZaiFdW6kj4c0ysmvPixJr9AARAAvccCWWIMYF8xTLsQaXwcPhm4wMQwAA0Ph+AHJJjosMx8BgcDTNfAm5oUOhsHgCGAfRQMPH6IhOPH-vWnPOLZLiOiRrhuW47vA7RwM6OBXs4PZAA)